# ABAP OLE - Checking if an OLE object is password protected

Tags: ole, abap

So I want to open a password protected excel file prompting the user to enter the password BUT I want to check that the file does in fact require a password before I prompt the user.

My current approach is this and does work.

```
CREATE OBJECT app 'EXCEL.APPLICATION'.
CALL METHOD OF app 'WORKBOOKS' = workbook.
CALL METHOD OF workbook 'OPEN'
  EXPORTING
  #1 = arch               "filename
  #2 = 0                  "Update links
  #3 = 0                  "ReadOnly
  #4 = 1                  "Format
  #5 = gv_password.       "password

 IF sy-subrc NE 0.

  CALL METHOD OF app 'QUIT'.
  FREE OBJECT app. FREE OBJECT workbook.
  CLEAR: app, workbook.
  CREATE OBJECT app 'EXCEL.APPLICATION'.

  gv_password = <user_entered_password>

  CALL METHOD OF app 'WORKBOOKS' = workbook.

  CALL METHOD OF workbook 'OPEN'
    EXPORTING
    #1 = arch               "filename
    #2 = 0                  "Update links
    #3 = 0                  "ReadOnly
    #4 = 1                  "Format
    #5 = gv_password.       "password

ENDIF.
```

This basically tries to open the excel file using a blank password and if that fails prompts the user. It's not a particularly fast or elegant solution though. Is there a better way? Perhaps checking a property directly before trying to open? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the following information, you cannot tell if an Excel file is password protected before opening it: http://www.mrexcel.com/archive/General/2130.html

In that discussion, they are basically suggesting what you are already doing. However, the last poster does suggest that passing a password to a non-password protected file has no effect, so you could always preemptively pass the password as an alternative (depending on the logic of your application).